# angularjs $scope variable fetching data from table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a web app in which I have training numbers which I have fetched from my table

Here is my controller with static training number:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function($scope) {

  $scope.total = 0;

  $scope.train = [{
      name: 'a',
      train: '100'
    }, {
      name: 'b',
      train: '200'
    }, {
      name: 'c',
      train: '300'
    }, {
      name: 'd',
      train: '400'
    }, {
      name: 'e',
      train: '500'
    }, {
      name: 'f',
      train: '600'
    }, {
      name: 'g',
      train: '700'
    }, {
      name: 'h',
      train: '800'
    }, {
      name: 'i',
      train: '900'
    }, {
      name: 'j',
      train: '1000'
    }

  ];

  $scope.calculateTotal = function(a) {
    if (a.checked) {
      $scope.total -= a.train;
    } else {
      $scope.total += a.train;
    }
  }


})
```

this is how my controller looks like

and this is my table

```
<table>
     <tbody>
       <tr data-ng-repeat="a in train">
         <td>
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="a.checked" data-ng-click="calculateTotal(a)"/>{{a.train}}
         </td>

       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>

   <h4>Total : {{All Trainingno}}</h4>
```

this is working fine if i add multiple training number but failed miserably when i remove trainng number

I WANT THEM TO BE LIKE(`100,200,300,400`) WHEN I CHECK THE CHECKBOX AND THE PROBLEM STARTS WHEN I UNCHECK THE CHECKBOX(`100200300400`) THIS IS WHAT HAPPEN WHEN I CHECKED 100,200,300 AND 400(`100200299400`) THESE FIGURE I GOT AFTER UNCHECKING THEM ALL

i created a fiddle please help me out here

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/XNVj3/2234/)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$scope.calculateTotal = function(a) {
  if (a.checked) {
    $scope.total -= a.train;
  } else {
    $scope.total += a.train;
  }
}
```

Should be changed to this:

```
$scope.calculateTotal = function(a) {
  if (a.checked) {
    $scope.total -= Number(a.train); // casting string to number
  } else {
    $scope.total += Number(a.train); // casting string to number
  }
}
```

As you are using string's in the `$scope.train.train`, or you can change them to integers...

```
$scope.train = [{
  name: 'a',
  train: 100 // no '
}, {
  ...
}]
```

---

Update:

```
$scope.calculateTotal = function(a) {
  if (a.checked) {
    var index = $scope.total.indexOf(Number(a.train))
    if (index > -1) {
      $scope.total.splice(index, 1);
    }
  } else {
    $scope.total.push(Number(a.train))
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/agm0m62z/

Comment: i know but these training numbers are coming from a table and i dont have permissions for changing that

Comment: Then cast them with `Number( ... )` ;D

Comment: UPDATED MY QUESTION

Comment: @MumbaiWadala Updated my answer.

Comment: Didn't save the fiddle, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Convert a.train to Number. As a.train is String, adding 2 string just concat the value. But In the case subtraction, if you substract Number with String, It auto converts String to Number.

Ex:

```
var a = 1;
    var b = "2";
    var c = a+b;  //12
        c= a-b    //-1


This will work for you.

$scope.calculateTotal = function(a) {
    if (a.checked) {
      $scope.total -= Number(a.train);
    } else {
      $scope.total += Number(a.train);
    }
  }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XNVj3/2235/

Edit:

```
 $scope.calculateTotal = function(a) {
    if (a.checked) {
       var index = $scope.total.indexOf(a.train)

         $scope.total.splice(index,1)
    } else {
    $scope.total.push(a.train);

    }

  }
```

Comment: I DONT WANT TO ADD THEM I WANT THEM TO BE LIKE(`100,200,300,400`) AND THE PROBLEM STARTS WHEN I UNCHECK THE CHECKBOX(`100200300400`) THIS IS WHAT HAPPEN WHEN I CHECKED 100,200,300 AND 400(`100200299400`) THESE FIGURE I GOT AFTER UNCHECKING THEM ALL

Comment: Got you. You can do this by pushing them to array and removing them.

Comment: Edited. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

this works the way you expect :

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function($scope) {

  $scope.total = [];

  $scope.train = [{
      name: 'a',
      train: '100'
    }, {
      name: 'b',
      train: '200'
    }, {
      name: 'c',
      train: '300'
    }, {
      name: 'd',
      train: '400'
    }, {
      name: 'e',
      train: '500'
    }, {
      name: 'f',
      train: '600'
    }, {
      name: 'g',
      train: '700'
    }, {
      name: 'h',
      train: '800'
    }, {
      name: 'i',
      train: '900'
    }, {
      name: 'j',
      train: '1000'
    }

  ];

  $scope.calculateTotal = function(a) {
    if (a.checked) {
       $scope.total.push(a.train);
    } else {
      $scope.total.splice($scope.total.indexOf(a));
    
     
    }
  }


})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">


  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>


  <body data-ng-controller="myController">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="a in train">
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="a.checked" data-ng-click="calculateTotal(a)" />{{a.train}}
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <h4>Total : {{total}}</h4>


  </body>

</html>
```